# railsでER図を出力するためerdを導入しましたがエラーが出ます

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

railsでER図を出力するためerdを導入しましたがエラーが出ます。

試したのはこちらの手順です。

[Rails ERDでER図を自動作成しよう！オプションも網羅](https://www.sejuku.net/blog/66196)

しかし `erd` コマンドを行ってもエラー "Failed: NameError: uninitialized constant RailsERD::CLI::ActiveRecord" が発生します。

```
bundle exec erd filetype=dot
Loading application in 'filetype=dot'...
Tried to load your application environment from 'filetype=dot/config/environment.rb' but the file was not present.
This means that your models might not get loaded fully when the diagram gets built. This can
make your entity diagram incomplete.

However, if you are using ActiveRecord without Rails just make sure your models get
loaded eagerly before we generate the ERD (for example, explicitly require your application
bootstrap file before calling rails-erd from your Rakefile). We will continue without loading the environment file,
and recommend you check your diagram for missing models after it gets generated.
Failed: NameError: uninitialized constant RailsERD::CLI::ActiveRecord

      $stderr.puts "Generating entity-relationship diagram for #{ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.length} models..."
```

エラー文のActiveRecordを初期化できないため発生するを調べてもそれらしい情報が出てきませんでした。
エラー対応の方法を捜索中です。

Answer (score 1):

参照している記事にも記載がありますが、ER 図の出力に Graphviz のインストールが必要なようです。こちらは事前に導入済みでしょうか？

また、エラーメッセージで検索すると以下の Issue がヒットします。[コメントの一つ](https://github.com/voormedia/rails-erd/issues/164#issuecomment-243102892) でやはり Graphviz に触れており、こちらをインストールすることで動作したという報告があるようです。

[Unable to generate ERD · Issue #164 · voormedia/rails-erd](https://github.com/voormedia/rails-erd/issues/164)

> run `bundle exec erd` in the root of the application
> before that do,
> `sudo apt-get install graphviz graphviz-dev`
> `gem install ruby-graphviz`
> It works for me

Comment: 当方、windowsを使用していて開発環境のひとつとしてWSL2のUBUNTU20.04を使っているため
gem install ruby-graphviz
でインストールしているのですが、どうもgraphvizを認識してくれないですね。

windows側でもgraphvizクライアントをインストールしていますが、powershellでの実行時に認識してくれません。

Comment: いずれの環境でも、graphviz をインストールのであれば、適切な PATH 設定が必要かと思います。

Comment: pathは既に設定済み dot=C:\Program Files\Graphviz\bin